Unity camera teleports to a right limit when reaching left limit
So, I'm trying to make a Sea of Thieves like-game, and I'm trying to set up a camera limit. Everything works fine until I give ycamlimitwheensteering a value bigger than 90. I'm losing my mind here. Someone please help. When it's bigger than 90 and you reach a left-limit, the camera teleports to the right limit.
using UnityEngine;

public class MouseLook : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float mouseSensitivity = 100f;
    public Transform playerBody;

    float xRotation = 0f;
    float yRotation = 0f;

    private bool isLerping = false;

    private bool isSteeringWheel;

    [SerializeField] public int YCamLimitWhenSteering = 70;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.Locked;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (isLerping) return; // Zablokuj kontrolę nad kamerą, jeśli jest lerpowanie

        float mouseX = Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") * mouseSensitivity * Time.deltaTime;
        float mouseY = Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y") * mouseSensitivity * Time.deltaTime;

        // Rotacja osi X (pionowa)
        xRotation -= mouseY;
        xRotation = Mathf.Clamp(xRotation, -90f, 90f);
        transform.localRotation = Quaternion.Euler(xRotation, 0f, 0f);

        if (isSteeringWheel)
        {
            yRotation += mouseX;

            // Oblicz nowe ograniczenia

            float minY = 90f - YCamLimitWhenSteering;
            float maxY = 90f + YCamLimitWhenSteering;


            if (yRotation < minY)
            {
                yRotation = minY;
            }
            else if (yRotation > maxY)
            {
                yRotation = maxY;
            }

            playerBody.localRotation = Quaternion.Euler(0f, yRotation, 0f);
        }
        else
        {
            playerBody.Rotate(Vector3.up * mouseX);
        }


    }


    public void SetSteering(bool isAtWheel)
    {
        isSteeringWheel = isAtWheel;

        // Jeśli gracz zaczyna sterować, ustaw yRotation na aktualną rotację
        if (isAtWheel)
        {
            yRotation = playerBody.localRotation.eulerAngles.y;
        }
    }

    public void SetLerping(bool lerping)
    {
        isLerping = lerping;
    }

}

I expected it to block when it reaches some value, but it doesnt work. Also, it's using additional 90f because when I'm not using it the front view is like the left, so I need to add 90 to actually generate limits from the front view.

So, lets walk through the code that matters
            float minY = 90f - YCamLimitWhenSteering;
        float maxY = 90f + YCamLimitWhenSteering;


        if (yRotation < minY)
        {
            yRotation = minY;
        }
        else if (yRotation > maxY)
        {
            yRotation = maxY;
        }

OK so, lets say you set YCamlimitWhenStearing to 5.
this makes minY 90-5, so 85, and maxY to 95.
But with a value of 5, you're still gonna hard look right as a whole.
Now, part of me assumes, the minY should have been -90f  so, left  then, and part of the reason that can happen is unity sometimes, if say -90, actually shows 270 ....
The most important part would be, debug, put debug statements in, show values as it moves around, so you can see what it has, and where its going and what code is excuting and because you now have the values, why.

alright i figured out that thats because unity rotation is 0 - 360 and i use -180 - 180. so now if i convert it to 360 rotation, the problem is still active because if i for example set limit to 110f, then the limits are 200 and 340 and when i go below 0 (360) it teleports me to 200

because you havent adjusted the logic. if you need it to be say 200, eg -160, then your best answer if its > 180, to subtract it from 360 to get the negative we humans expect right?

so can you please change my code so that it works? im a beginner programmist and i realy dont understand the solution
